# Upgrading IBsonSerializer with Mongo driver 2

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-csharp-2.0

The old implementation of the Mongo Drivers was leading to this kind of code:

```
public object Deserialize(BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType, Type actualType)
{
    if (nominalType == typeof(T))
    {
        if (typeof(V) == typeof(string))
            return _deSerializeFunc(bsonReader.ReadString());
        else if (typeof(V) == typeof(int))
            return _deSerializeFunc(bsonReader.ReadInt32());
        else if (typeof(V) == typeof(double))
            return _deSerializeFunc(bsonReader.ReadDouble());
        else if (typeof(V) == typeof(decimal))
            return _deSerializeFunc((decimal)bsonReader.ReadDouble());
    }
    return null;
}
```

The new interface is completely different. How can I start implementing the previous code with this new interface?

```
public object Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
{
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at my open source [PubComp.NoSql.MongoDbDriver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PubComp.NoSql.MongoDbDriver/) which abstracts issues like this. It is still using the legacy API of the MongoDB C# Driver v2.0 due to current lack of support in the driver for IQueryable() (expected in v2.1), FileSets and Indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the 2.0 version of the .NET driver we needed to pass more information to the serializers. Rather than adding more parameters to the methods, we packaged the parameters into two new parameters. The context parameter holds values that should be constant for an entire serialization operation, and the args parameter holds values that change at each level when serializing complex types.

It should be relatively easy to port to the new design:

1. The reader parameter is now in context.Reader
2. The nominalType parameter is now in args.NominalType
3. The actualType parameter has gone away

Regarding the actualType, it is now the responsibility of each serializer to determine the actual type (using whatever conventions it wants), and to lookup and delegate to the actual serializer when the actual type is different than the nominal type. If the class you are serializing is not polymorphic, then the nominal type and the actual type are always the same anyway.